# What is the difference between Anti-national and Anti-nationalist? When is one used over the other?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, philosophy

Merriam-Webster dictionary shows slightly different definitions of both the terms.
However, [Urban-dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Anti-nationalist) shows the definition of Anti-nationalist similar to anti-national in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-national) dictionary.
Also, different sites show different meanings.

Can anyone explain the difference between both the terms to a non-native English speaker?

Edit 1: Oxford dictionary has only the meaning of Anti-national. So, is it possible that Anti-national is preferred term in British English?

Edit 2: Check this link to see how Anti-national is used in Indian English media: https://m.economictimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/view-will-the-real-anti-national-damaging-bharat-please-stand-up/amp_articleshow/61515366.cms

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question and provide links to your sources.

Comment: I'd think of an anti-national as one thinking or acting against the state, while an anti-nationalist would be one who believes in and/or professes anti-national sentiment.

Comment: Urban dictionary isn't really the most reputable of sources.

Comment: @kris To me an anti-nationalist doesn't usually have sentiments or beliefs which are in opposition to a given state but is opposed to nationalism which is the extreme, often near or neo fascist, version of patriotism.

Comment: @BoldBen That's another way of looking at it. Like "100% natural latex." Is it "100%  latex which is natural" or "latex that's 100% natural"? Take your choice.

Comment: @Kris Not really, anti-nationalists by my definition would not be unpatriotic or working against the state, they would only be opposed to organisations which take an extreme nationalist viewpoint. Of course there are those who recognise only the extreme nationalist point of view as being patriotic and see patriotic anti-nationalists as being anti-national, which they are not.

Answer (score -1):

That's much more easily seen in the positive forms, *national* and *nationalist*.

For instance, *national sentiment* is the sentiment shared by the majority of the nation and *nationalist sentiment* is sentiment aspiring to nationhood, however few people share it.

One contemporary example is Brexit, by which the *national sentiment* supports *nationalist* moves, even if only by a slight majority.

Comment: I don't think that's what the Q is about, though.

Comment: Your answer makes me conclude that anti-national sentiment is the sentiment shared by the majority of the people who do not wish to associate themselves with a nation, & anti-nationalist sentiment is the sentiment against the existence of a nation. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Really, Kris? I thought *What is the difference between Anti-national and Anti-nationalist* was pretty clear but if you don't think that's what the Q is about, what is it about, please?

Comment: Sparsh, that does sound pretty-much right and if we're digging deeper please, why did you ask? There are so many different aspects to this.

Looking at it again, I'm not sure such a thing as *Anti-national sentiment* is possible outside logic and theoretical grammar.

Anti-British, anti-German, anti-Birkino Fassian or Ruritanian, of course but anti-national now seems far too generic.

*Those people who share the characteristic of harbouring dislike of their own nations* doesn't really work for me.

Anyone?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In Indian English media, "Anti-national" is often used for people who are pro-separatists or/and oppose the integrity of India. This Indian media's definition is a little different from what I concluded from your answer. I guess, we can say that the definitions of both of these words are not yet fixed, and are region-dependent. Maybe because of the unpopularity of Anti-national/Anti-nationalist sentiments, the meanings of these words haven't attained saturation.

Comment: Ah… even though Indian English is a law unto, surely your question was about the difference between two terms, rather than their similarity?

Doesn't whichever point of view sees *… the unpopularity of Anti-national/Anti-nationalist sentiments* also suggest any difference is much less important?

Comment: Well, for few people (like communists, separatists, and internationalists) its difference is really important because these labels are a part of their identity, which defines their ideology. ...  And, your answer makes me interpret that being called an Anti-national is more generous than being called an Anti-nationalist. However, @Kris comment on my question makes me interpret the opposite. Are you both from different countries or cultures?

Comment: Is Anti-national capitalized for a specific movement, or generically lower case?

Without a capital, it seems to me using anti-national for people who are pro-separatists or/and oppose the integrity of India begs two questions.

How is *anti-national* different from *separatist*?

Presumably *internationalists* want a corporate take-over or League of Nations/UN-like unification ‘upwards.’ Isn’t *separatist* necessarily ‘downwards’ though? Separate India - anywhere - into what that’s not itself a state?

Somewhere like Quora this might be fun. Here it will soon be asked to move…

Comment: Nah, anti-national isn't capitalized. Use of 'anti-national' for both internationalists & separatists is wrong, but that's how it is used here, maybe because both ideologies oppose the existence of India as a sovereign state... And, I didn't understood your last line.

Comment: Oh. That last meant we seem to have reached the limit of what many at ELU will consider a discussion about language, and stand on the brink of politics.

Whether anti-national is capitalized is purely about structure. Whether it's appropriate for both internationalists & separatists moves into content and meaning.

In Britain the question doesn't arise because anti-*unionists* Irish, Scots or Welsh are all nationalists. That I have no idea how that equates to Indian's use of *anti-national* for either internationalists or separatists can hardly be a question of dialect or idiom…

Comment: I think the word "nationalist" varies too much between countries/cultures to make this easy to answer.  To some, it seems, nationalist means "Someone who wants a unified nation" and to others it means "Someone who wants their country to be independent", two meanings which are almost opposite to one another.  Furthermore, in many countries, "nationalism" has become entangled with xenophobia and/or racism, further complicating the issue.